# Install ATI Radeon HD 3450 (RV620 LE) in Ubuntu 13.10 (64bits)

Tags: 13.10, ati, graphics, radeon

---

I failed to install the driver for my ATI Radeon HD 3450 (RV620 LE) card in Ubuntu 13.10 (64bit)

someone could help me with this, to know if they can or not.

I have tried several ways to install the driver but always I have to reinstall the xorg again, because after not let me sign in ubuntu.

I hope someone help me with this problem

Comment: There's already an article on ubuntu.com on how to install Radeon drivers. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, 

but apparently this card only supports the open driver, not the driver closed. q and I would like it to be the fastest to install some video games and animations on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

For that card the only proprietary driver you could use is the legacy driver...however that one only works with linux kernel up to 3.4.x which was in use back in Ubuntu 12.04.2.
So you can only use the default open-source `radeon` driver that is already installed.
Performance wise you'd be unlikely to see a big difference anyways, as the older cards are from my experience pretty well supported by the open-source driver.